# Create movable/resizable elements of list of control in Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, data-binding

I followed this code to create a resizable/movable canvas. And I want to put an `ItemsControl` to `Canvas`:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Units}"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="0">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Canvas/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
              Value="{Binding X}" />
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
              Value="{Binding Y}" />
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}"
                        Canvas.Left="{Binding X}"
                        Width="{Binding Width}"
                        Height="{Binding Height}"
                        Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
          <Rectangle IsHitTestVisible="False"
            Fill="Black" />
        </ContentControl>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But when I resize or move item, the value of `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` don't change, I think because their value are bound from `ContentPresenter`, not `ContentControl`.
How can I fix that? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have that ContentControl at all? You could set all the properties in the ItemContainerStyle. Besides that, `Mode=OneTime` on the `Canvas.Left` binding doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I use ContentControl for binding a template that helps rezise and move canvas

Comment: @Clemens please give me some advices, How can I set Template (like in ContentControl) in Style ContentPresenter?